# Export WordPress complete URL list for redirects (website migration)

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console, yoast

My WordPress website is completely rebuilt with AEM. The WordPress instance will be taken offline and the AEM instance will go online. With the same domain but the url structure will no longer be the same as also the structure of the website will be new.

Problem: This will cause various WordPress URLs to generate a 404 error later.

My goal: I want to export all WordPress URLs as CSV structured and can therefore set up redirects. Structured means as far as its possible:

- A separation is made between pages and posts
- Public pages only
- etc.

**Here is the question: What is the best way to export them and that they are also structured? Is there a plugin, just take a sitemap, maybe Google Search Console or directly from the database?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try using export-all-urls plugin. Below links will help you export the URLs.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-all-urls/
https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/how-to-export-wordpress-urls-to-text-or-csv-files/

If you have a pattern in the existing URLs, then you might not have to add rewrite rule for each and every URL. Instead use regex to map all URLs following the pattern to AEM URLs.